# How to pass parameter field to 'Command query' in crystal reports 8.5

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

am using CR 8.5 to generate report.I am passing a parameter field from VB to crystal report.
I have added the SQL query for the report in which the "WHERE" condition is got from the parameter field.

say
    select * from tableA where column1='{?prameter1}'

The report is empty when i preview.. Please advise what am i missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the older versions of Crystal, it wasn't possible to amend queries to include parameter values - you could only add constant values. Consequently, your amended query is selecting records from tableA where column1 is equal to the string "{?prameter1}", not the *value* of parameter {?prameter1}.

In order to select by the parameter value, reset the query to its default value - probably:

```
select * from tableA
```

and add a condition to the Crystal record selection dialog:

```
{tableA.column1} = {?prameter1}
```

(Note - no quotes in the latter condition.)

EDIT:

As noted above, you need to **remove the parameter from the query**, because it is passed to SQL **exactly** the way you see it when using Show Query in Crystal. If you amend the query to `select * from tableA where column1={?prameter1}`, Crystal will attempt to run that exact string as a SQL statement, and will therefore return an error - it will not attempt to substitute the value of the parameter into the SQL statement.

However, if you add a Crystal record selection condition using the parameter into the report, Crystal will attempt to add the selection condition to SQL when running the report - if you use Show Query **after** adding the Crystal record selection formula, it should first prompt you for a value for your parameter, and then show you a query that includes your selection condition (with the *entered value* of the parameter, not the parameter name).

There are a couple of restrictions on this automatic addition of Crystal record selection conditions to SQL:

- the SQL query **must** be uncustomised (ie. no changes made to the default version of the query), otherwise Crystal will not try to amend the query - the customisation takes precedence. (This is why you **have** to reset the query to its default form.)
- the Crystal record selection criteria need to be relatively simple - a series of `and` conditions on database and parameter field values are normally OK, but a mixture of `and` and `or` conditions, or conditions on Crystal formula values, will probably result in Crystal not amending the query conditions.

Comment: Mark, Here Column1 is a string datatype hence I have added with quotes.after removing quote I get
    "SQL syntax error,Line 1: Parse error '?' (0x3f)"

Comment: The point which I have added parameter in sql bcoz the table is very huge and i guess sql query fetches fast instead of record selection (correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: @jeyaganesh: see my edit above. Including the condition in the query will be more efficient, but you can't do this with parameter values by amending the query in Crystal 8.5 - you have to add the parameter to the Crystal record selection formula, and let Crystal substitute it for you.

Comment: I am finding the report is generating very slowly. I believe it is due to the query. If I could pass the parameter values to be part of the SQL, I am thinking only the required result set would appear versus the entire results of the query then the filtering after that?

Comment: @SunWKim: The point of this answer us that Crystal **automatically** adds the filter criteria **to the query** (for relatively simple criteria) before running the query. If you use Show Query, do you see your filter criteria added to the query expression?

Comment: @MarkBannister Nope. I just see the Command custom query. The parameters are passed at some point to filter the results, but I'd like for them to be part of the where clause. I created the parameters from the Design part of the screen, not Edit Command where seems to be a different Parameter feature....?